# When creating a Restful API in Zend Framework, can you use modules?

Tags: api, zend-framework, module, zend-framework-modules

When creating a Restful API in Zend Framework, can you use modules? If so, can one explain how? with an example pref. (or a link with supporting documents)

I have modules called:

Product

- may have one controller

Entity

may have more than one controller eg.

- /customer
- /supplier

In each I have an Index Controller with the methods:

Get

Post

Put

Delete

Example:

Products/index/?id=1&name=test (will add)

However I want to remove the word index so its this instead:
Products/?id=1&name=test (will add)

I can do that with the help of Zend_Controller_Router_Route but it does not pass the request, ive looked at getMethod, but you can not do that at bootstrap stage.

Is there any way that you can use modular Zend Framework application as a restful API?

Comment: Without any information about your bootstrap / routing this is hard to fix. You should have a look at the REST-router aswell: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.rest.route_usage

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

You must use Zend_Rest_Route. It route the request by the method to the right action. There is one bug which prevents configuring the rest route in the configuration file, so you must add the route in the bootstrap.

```php
<?php
protected function _initRestRoute()
{
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front->getRouter();
    $restRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route(
        $front,
        array(),     //Defaults
        array('api') //Restful modules
    );
    $router->addRoute('rest', $restRoute);
}
```

By default if you give a URL like this, the 123 is bind to the variable $id

```
products/123
```

You can also specify the Url like so, when the variables are bind '123' -> $id and 'test' -> $name

```
products/id/123/name/test
```

The controllers should extend the Zend_Rest_Controller class